# xcode saying my textboxes from interface builder are undeclared

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to make my app save when I hit the home button following a tutorial http://mobileorchard.com/how-to-make-an-iphone-app-part-6-saving-data/
I'm finished the tutorial (using code I'm already working on rather than making something new for the tutorial) and I have the errors q1, q2 are undeclared (they are my text boxes in IB)

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
//TEST 
NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:q1.text,q2.text,nil];
[values writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];
[values release];
//TEST
}
```

This is my .h for the view:

```
#import "Spalsh_XcodeAppDelegate.h"
#import "MainControllerView.h"

@implementation Spalsh_XcodeAppDelegate
@synthesize window=_window;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   MainControllerView *mainController = [[MainControllerView alloc] init];

[_window addSubview:mainController.view];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
 Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
 */
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
//TEST 
NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:q1.text,q2.text,nil];
[values writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];
[values release];
//TEST
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
 */
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
 */
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Called when the application is about to terminate.
 Save data if appropriate.
 See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
 */
}

- (void)dealloc
{
[_window release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: show us your .h code, have you connected up q1 and q2 in interface builder?

Comment: I just posted my .h howq do I connect my q1 and q2 in interface builder?

Comment: Thats the code for your appDeleagte, where is the code for your .h and .m  in MainControllerView.h?

Answer (score 0):

But where are q1 and q2 textfields are declared? In which view controller, did you create them via Interface builder or via code whatever. And how come they will be acknowledged in the method `applicationDidEnterBackground` where in `NSArray` object you are adding them to it?

As far as I see it, you are trying to save some value from some view controller's text field text in `AppDelegate`'s `applicationDidEnterBackground` method. To do that, you'll have to save the text in strings in some property. Point to the view controller in view hierarchy , and get those strings from those properties of that instance. And from there then, you'll be able to save it to array or do any other proceedings with them.